# Collecting Warning and Error logs in a file?

Tags: android, error-logging, android-logcat

How can i  collect only  my app  warning and error logs in a file.(I used logcat -d but it gets all logs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `adb logcat -s "THETAGYOUWANTTOFOLLOW"`. Most of the time I use the full logs to debug though. It is easy to find your app logs with the coloredlogcat.py script and having all the logs can help me understanding more easily what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse then you can easily collect all your logs & warning using "Export Selected Items To Text File" Button.[image]